# Minimum version of DB that supports paging queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, postgresql

We are currently supports following Database in our project.

1. MS SQL
2. Oracle
3. MySQL
4. PostgreSQL
5. DB2

We would like to implement paging queries for these databases. I would like to know what is the minimum version that support paging queries.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Do you mean order by and offset?

Comment: Yes. Offset and limit

Answer (score 0):

All these database support pagination.

You should not use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` for pagination, because of the known problems:

- The performance becomes much worse as the offset grows.
- Concurrent insertions and deletions lead to unexpected repetitions and gaps.

Instead, use *keyset pagination*, which will work with any of these database systems, at least as long as you want to sort the result only by a single column.

Read [this article](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) and look at [the slides](https://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/p2d2-pagination-done-the-postgresql-way) for more.